# Try to change font in list item and get error with getAssets method (bcs class extends from CursorAdapter)

Tags: java, android, listview, fonts, material-design

I am using list. Want to change font in it items. Theres a title textview and description. All views are initialized in adapter and they are final. Adapter extened from CursorAdapter thats why i can't use getAssets method.

So what i should do if im extended from CursorAdapter but at the same time i need to use AppCombat methods as getAssets?

Main activity:

```
        public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
            LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

        /** Identifier for the pet data loader */
        private static final int LIST_LOADER = 0;

        /** Adapter for the ListView */
        ListCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);
            // Changing font


            Log.v(TAG, "--- WE ARE IN CATALOG ACTIVITY ---");

            // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });



            // Find the ListView which will be populated with the list data
            ListView listListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


            // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
            View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
            listListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

            // Setup an Adapter to create a list item for each row of list data in the Cursor.
            // There is no items data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor.
            mCursorAdapter = new ListCursorAdapter(this, null);
            listListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

            // Setup the item click listener
            listListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ShoppingListBdHelper helper = new ShoppingListBdHelper(view.getContext());
                    if (helper.setCompleted(id)) {
                        mCursorAdapter.setCompleted(view);
                    }
                }
            });

            // Kick off the loader
            getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LIST_LOADER, null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_catalog.xml file.
            // This adds menu items to the app bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                // Respond to a click on the "Insert dummy data" menu option
                case R.id.action_share_button:
                    shareButton(mCursorAdapter.getCursor());
                    return true;
                // Respond to a click on the "Delete all entries" menu option
                case R.id.action_delete_all_entries:
                    deleteAllItems();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        /**
         * Share button
         */
        private void shareButton(Cursor cursor) {

            Log.v(TAG, "--- WE ARE IN SHARE BUTTON METHOD ---");

            List<String> test;
            test = new ArrayList<String>();
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "field: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME)));

                test.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME)) + " - " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION))); //add the item
//                test.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION))); //add the item
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            cursor.close();

//            for (String comma : )

            Log.v(TAG, "--- OUR LIST INCLUDES: " + test.toString());

            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<String>) test);
            myIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, test.toString());

            Log.v(TAG, "--- INTENT EXTRAS ARE: " + myIntent.getExtras());

            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share using"));
        }


        /**
         * Helper method to delete all list in the database.
         */
        private void deleteAllItems() {

            Log.v(TAG, "Сработал метод удаления всех данных");
            long rowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(ListContract.ListEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
            Log.v("CatalogActivity", rowsDeleted + " rows deleted from list database");
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Начал работать loader cursor");
            // Define a projection that specifies the columns from the table we care about.
            String[] projection = {
                    ListContract.ListEntry._ID,
                    ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME,
                    ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
                    ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_COMPLETED
            };

            // This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
            return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
                    ListContract.ListEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
                    projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                    null,                   // No selection clause
                    null,                   // No selection arguments
                    null);                  // Default sort order

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            // Update {@link ListCursorAdapter} with this new cursor containing updated pet data
            mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
            Log.v(TAG, "Cursor adapter загрузился");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            // Callback called when the data needs to be deleted
            mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }


    }
```

List adapter

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout

        final TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        final TextView summaryTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.summary);

        Typeface titleTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        Typeface descriptionTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Italic.ttf");
        Log.v(TAG, "--- FONT IS ---" + titleTypeface );
        nameTextView.setTypeface(titleTypeface);
        summaryTextView.setTypeface(descriptionTypeface);

        // Find the columns of pet attributes that we're interested in
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME);
        int breedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION);

        // Read the pet attributes from the Cursor for the current pet
        String petName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
        String petBreed = cursor.getString(breedColumnIndex);

        // If the pet breed is empty string or null, then use some default text
        // that says "Unknown breed", so the TextView isn't blank.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(petBreed)) {
            petBreed = context.getString(R.string.unknown_description);
        }

        // Update the TextViews with the attributes for the current pet
        nameTextView.setText(petName);
        summaryTextView.setText(petBreed);

        view.findViewById(R.id.editImageView).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "--- WE ARE IN IMAGEVIEW LISTENER ---");

                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditorActivity.class);

                        // Form the content URI that represents the specific pet that was clicked on,
                        // by appending the "id" (passed as input to this method) onto the
                        // {@link PetEntry#CONTENT_URI}.
                        // For example, the URI would be "content://com.example.android.pets/pets/2"
                        // if the pet with ID 2 was clicked on.
                        Uri currentPetUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                ListContract.ListEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListEntry._ID))
                        );


                        Log.v(TAG, "--- CONTENT URI " + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListEntry._ID)));

                        // Set the URI on the data field of the intent
                        intent.setData(currentPetUri);

                        // Launch the {@link EditorActivity} to display the data for the current pet.
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );

        view.findViewById(R.id.leftSide).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "--- WE ARE IN LEFTSIDE LISTENER ---");
//
//                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditorActivity.class);
//
//                        // Form the content URI that represents the specific pet that was clicked on,
//                        // by appending the "id" (passed as input to this method) onto the
//                        // {@link PetEntry#CONTENT_URI}.
//                        // For example, the URI would be "content://com.example.android.pets/pets/2"
//                        // if the pet with ID 2 was clicked on.
//                        Uri currentPetUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
//                                ListContract.ListEntry.CONTENT_URI,
//                                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListEntry._ID))
//                        );
//
//                        // Set the URI on the data field of the intent
//                        intent.setData(currentPetUri);
//
//                        // Launch the {@link EditorActivity} to display the data for the current pet.
//                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

                        nameTextView.setPaintFlags(nameTextView.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                        summaryTextView.setPaintFlags(summaryTextView.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

                    }
                }
        );

        Boolean completed = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_COMPLETED)) == 1;
        if (completed) {
            setCompleted(view);
        }
    }
```

Error type 2

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.android.list, PID: 10811
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.list/com.example.android.list.CatalogActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.android.list.CatalogActivity.onCreate(CatalogActivity.java:69)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: post your error log

Comment: @Reena please chwck the error

Comment: what is the value print in this log.Log.v(TAG, "--- FONT IS ---" + titleTypeface );

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @dipali --- FONT IS ---android.graphics.Typeface@1e8d9132

Comment: @VladMatvienko i know what is null exception. I understand how does it works. But here i dont know where do i need to initialize views right to have opportunity give them new fonts